# Does calling useAuth function in Firebase always call to backend?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I have this code where I'm building a user account with Firebase Authentication:

```js
export default function Account() {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(getAuth())
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Box sx={{ mt: "3rem" }}>
        <Typography variant="h2">Welcome {user.displayName}!</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

If I include this same model for each NextJS page, will the call to the Firebase backend happen for each time with `getAuth()`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, but by default, `getAuth` will not call to your identity provider (IdP) if no `app` instance is provided. However, there is more.

For example, if you use `getAuth(yourApp).verifyIdTokens(yourToken)`, `firebase-admin-sdk` will decode your JWT only on your server using a cached cryptographic key. If a key is valid, but in reality, it has been revoked from IdP, the promise still returns a valid result. If you add `verifyIdToken(yourToken, true)`, then at this point, your backend will make a call to IdP to verify if the token is still valid in reality. If not, an error is raised.

For more information, you can read [an official document regarding this.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#detect_id_token_revocation)